# bash not equal operator not working

Tags: bash

I've been writing a bash script and I cannot figure out why the != operator is not working.

```
#/bin/bash
vips=()
vips+=("        Ltm::HTTP Profile: Default_HTTP_Profile")
vips+=("        Ltm::Virtual Address: 10.206.16.76")
for i in "${vips[@]}";
do
    if [[ $i != *"TCP Profile"* ]] || [[ $i != *"OneConnect"* ]] || [[ $i != *"HTTP Profile"* ]]; then
        echo "test"
    fi
done
for i in "${vips[@]}";
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The result from this is

```
    test
    test
        Ltm::HTTP Profile: Default_HTTP_Profile
        Ltm::Virtual Address: 10.206.16.76
```

As you can see the 2nd array element should no match the if logic.

Comment: Why would it ever get to the third branch when the first one returns true?

Comment: 1. Quote your variables. 2. Run with `set -x` to see what's actually being run.

Comment: ok I am dumb.  I see your point.  The first branch will match both so the -or operator won't work.  Looks like I need a nested IF to do what I want.

Comment: No need for a nested if.

Comment: @CodeGnome, all the necessary quotes are already there. `[[ ]]` suppresses string-splitting and glob expansion, and quotes have special meaning (which we don't want in this case) on the right-hand side of its `=`, `!=` and `~=` operations.

Comment: Just change your `||` to `&&` -- "if it's not equal to x AND it's not equal to y AND it's not equal to z, then ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's trace how this executes:

```
i="        Ltm::HTTP Profile: Default_HTTP_Profile"
if [[ $i != *"TCP Profile"* ]] || [[ $i != *"OneConnect"* ]] || [[ $i != *"HTTP Profile"* ]]; then
```

First, it runs `[[ $i != *"TCP Profile"* ]]`. This test returns true, because the string doesn't contain `TCP Profile`. Thus, the `if` is true as a whole, and it doesn't need to run any other tests.

---

What you presumably **want**, however, is the following:

```
case $i in
   *"TCP Profile"*|*"OneConnect"*|*"HTTP Profile"*) : ;; # do nothing
   *) echo "test" ;;
esac
```

...or, alternatively:

```
if ! [[ $i = *"TCP Profile"* || $i = *"OneConnect"* || $i = *"HTTP Profile"* ]]; then
  echo "test"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I revised my logic as follows and it works.  Thanks for the help.

```
if [[ $i == *"TCP Profile"* ]] || [[ $i == *"OneConnect"* ]] || [[ $i == *"HTTP Profile"* ]]; then
    :   
else        
    echo "test"
fi
```